# NoMethod Error undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Running
Rails 4.1.8 | 
Ruby 2.1.5p273

I'm trying to display the current username for notes that are created from current user using:

`<%= "#{note.user.first_name.capitalize} #{note.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}" %>` in show.html.erb.

```
<% @notes.each do |note| %>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h4>
             <%= "#{note.user.first_name.capitalize} #{note.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}" %>
            </h4>
            <p><%= note.created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y") %></p>
          </td>

          <td>
            <p><%= h(note.comment).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>
```

If I take `<%= "#{note.user.first_name.capitalize} #{note.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}" %>` the app works just fine.

I also checked the NotesController for note as well and I can't seem to find the issue.

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_note, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_account
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /notes/new
  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end

  # GET /notes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /notes
  # POST /notes.json
  def create
    @note = Note.new(note_params)
    @note.user_id = current_user.id
    @note.account_id = @account.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.save
        format.html { redirect_to @account, notice: 'note was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @note }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /notes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /notes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @note.update(note_params)
        format.html { redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'note was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @note }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /notes/1
  # DELETE /notes/1.json
  def destroy
    @note.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to account_path(@account), notice: 'note was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_note
      @note = note.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:account_id])
    end

     def check_user
      unless (@note.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?)
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, this note belongs to someone else"
      end
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:comment)
    end
end
```

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing, I just can't see it.

Comment: `note.user` is nil for on of the notes

Comment: Your code is a little wired. There should be a `show` action here to map with your `show.html.erb` file. In this file, you should use a variable named `note` instead of  `notes`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a note that does not have a user associated with it, or one of the note users does not have first_name or a last_name (we would had known if you had posted the error message you are getting). If you want to guard against this, you have to make sure the user, first_name and last_name are not nil before calling methods on them:

**In model:**

```
def display_user_name
  if user.nil?
    "No user"
  else
    "#{user.first_name.present? ? user.first_name : '<missing>'} "\
    "#{user.last_name.present? ? user.last_name.capitalize[0] : '<missing>'}"
  end
end
```

**In template:**

```
<%= note.display_user_name %>
```

OR, you can use the great `andand` gem, then in your template you will have:

```
"#{note.user.andand.first_name.andand.capitalize} #{note.user.andand.last_name.andand.capitalize[0]}"
```

Just note that it will return " " (a string with a space in it) if the note has not user or has no first name and no last name.

Comment: It would be much better to figure out why this is happening and update the model and associations to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Of course, but that would depend on project needs/requirements which would dictate whether the scenarios we are guarding against should be prevented from happening or are valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in `Note` class *app/models/note.rb*:

```
def user_name
  @user_name ||= user.present? ? "#{user.first_name.capitalize} #{user.last_name.capitalize[0]}" : "No user" # or Anonymous(whichever suites your requirement)
end
```

then in your show.html.erb:

```
<%= note.user_name %>
```

Here:

1. You have one place to edit for any future references of user name in your application.
2. You do not repeat yourself(DRY) when you need to show user name of a note.
3. Easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had serveral "notes" that had a few "null" values in the database which which is why it couldn't associated with the current_user.

[image]

After deleting those notes with null values, the problem was corrected.